# How to keep TeXLive up to date on gentoo?

Tags: gentoo, dependencies, latex, software-updates

The packages `dev-texlive/texlive*` are often outdated. As far I read it is not trivial to keep the TeXLive distribution package up to date or convert the `tlmgr` system to gentoo ebuilds.

As a solution one can install TeXLive with the `tlmgr` installer from https://www.tug.org/texlive/ in the user space and update on demand (several bugfixes and updates per day).

Unfortunately some gentoo packages depend on TeXLive and the package manager will not see the installation in the user space. And via verse some TeXLive-packages depend on software on the gentoo system.

As a workaround I installed `dev-texlive/texlive-latex` via package manager to satisfy most of the dependencies and then installed TeXLive (full installation) with `tlmgr` in the user space. Is there a better solution?

**How can I run a recent TeXlive setup with daily updates on gentoo Linux?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may add packages to `/etc/portage/profile/package.provided`:

```
dev-texlive/texlive-latex-2016
```

Please note that:

- you must include a version
- you must not use a leading equal sign

For more informations read [this](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki//etc/portage/profile/package.provided) Gentoo wiki article.

Update (2017-02-28): a new Gentoo wiki article has been published: [TeX Live manual installation](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/TeX_Live_manual_installation)

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. That is what I was looking for. Now I just need a good idea, which packages should be added. Should we add `dev-texlive/*` for a texlive full installation, or are things more complicate?

Comment: If I add that to `package.provided` I get the following error message: Invalid package name in package.provided: dev-texlive/*. I would start by adding texlive-latex-2016 only and if portage asks to install other texlive packages I would just add them to `package.provided` as the need arises.

Comment: The list gets quite long tlmgr installs more than just things from `dev-texlive/*` like `dev-tex/revtex-4.1_p2-r1`. I have no idea, how to maintain this list over some years. Would it make sense to add -9999 as version, because we will always update via tlmgr and get the freshest packages?

Comment: I don't know unfortunately. You may try asking on the Gentoo forums too, and/or on the gentoo-user mailing list.

Comment: @JonasStein: Thank you for sharing your knowledge on the newly created Gentoo wiki articles!

Comment: Wow, you found the wiki page just a minute after creation. I think this is an FAQ for many users and invite everybody to contribute. Thank you for adding the link to it.

Comment: This is because I have Gentoo wiki in my RSS feed reader :)